# Speedup web site loading CakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am doing a website in cakephp. I have a toolbar on the top which does not change over the pages.
I would do in such a way that when I click on a menu in the toolbar, the toolbar does not reload unnecessarily.
How can I do it? In jQuery?

Comment: "how can I do it"?.... do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery or any other JS framework of your choice or by simply writing your own code to do an AJAX request.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

In CakePHP detect using the RequestHandler (1.3) or using the request object (2.0) if the request was an ajax one and respond with whatever you want to return.